# MongoDB Text Search on Large Dataset

Tags: mongodb, search, optimization, database

I have a book collection with currently 7.7 million records and I have setup a text index as follows that will allow me to search the collection by `title` and `author` as follows:

```
db.book.createIndex( { title: "text", author: "text" }, {sparse: true, background: true, weights: {title: 15, author: 5}, name: "text_index"} )
```

The problem is when I use a search query that will return a lot of results eg `John` and then sort by the `textScore` the time to perform the query is over 60 seconds.

Please see an example query below:

```
db.runCommand(
  {
    aggregate: "book",
    pipeline : [
      { $match: { $text: { $search: "John" } } },
      { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
      { $limit: 6 }
    ],
    allowDiskUse : true
  }
)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to reduce this search time down to a reasonable level?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have the _feeling_ that using a [`find`query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#return-top-3-matching-documents) would perform better here. Could you test that ? Something along the lines of: `db.book.find(
   { $text: { $search: "John" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).limit(6)`

Comment: I have changed this as suggested to use `.find` syntax but the query is still running at around 50 seconds, any other ideas?

Comment: @BillMorrison Did you get any solution for this? Even I am running into similar issue. We have a large dataset and mongo text search query is returning results extremely slow.